# Azure Functions equivalent of Startup.cs in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure-ad-b2c

I would like to make a call to get a signing key from the JWKS endpoint (first issue) on Azure B2C and store it in memory (second issue). Thereafter I would get it from memory and use it to validate each JWT token (using jsonwebtoken library) that comes with a request to call any of my Azure functions. I do not want to make this call each and every time I get a request as there are synchronisation issues with he Azure function and the call to fetch the signing key.

My setup is as follows: a frontend React application that signs a user into Azure B2C and recives a token; an Azure Functions API that services all requests coming from the React app; Azure B2C tenant.

Comment: Yes, you can have a startup.cs file with Azure Functions.

Comment: You do understand that this has nothing to do with C#, right?

Comment: Why wouldn't it?  Azure function APIs can be written in multiple languages.  You don't mention the language you'd like it to be written in.  Why would we assume js when the title mentions cs.  That react app could be talking to an azure function written in csharp, go, python, js.  Coding is hard and complex.  Folks want to help.  Well-written questions demonstrate a respect for their time.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I know this question is old, but I had a similar issue. I used Azure AD Verify Token to solve my problem. https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-ad-verify-token
This package will help you solve issue one and issue two. This package is built to deal with Azure B2C.

```
const { verify, VerifyOptions } = require('azure-ad-verify-token');
const options: VerifyOptions = {
  jwksUri: 'https://contoso.b2clogin.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/discovery/v2.0/keys?p=b2c_1_signupsignin',
  issuer: 'https://contoso.b2clogin.com/{{tenant_id}}/v2.0/',
  audience: '99d1275c-e805-483f-b832-600f8130829c' // application ID
};
// verfity option
verify(token, options).then(decode => 
// code for decoding token 
console.log(decoded); })
.catch(err => //invalid token console.log(err)});
```

For storing tokens in memory, you can use this:

```
const { setConfig } = require('azure-ad-verify-token');
setConfig({
  cacheLifetime: 12 * (60 * 60 * 1000) // 12 hours
});
```